# Parse.com - Another user is already linked to this facebook id

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using parse.com's api and trying to link a currently active user to his to facebook account.

I keep bumbing into:

```
Another user is already linked to this facebook id
```

As to my question: How do I get the user's connected facebook id? I'd like to switch my current anonymous user with the active and logged in user.

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved this by logging out the current user then logging in. Works well.

```
[PFFacebookUtils linkUser:[PFUser currentUser] permissions:permissionsArray block:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (!success) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"User Cancelled");
        } else {
            if(error.code == 208) {
                [PFUser logOut];
                [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                    if(error) {
                        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
                    } else {
                        // Carry on
                    }
                }];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Carry on
    }
}];
```

Comment: Good workaround, however the error message still appears but the user gets linked to the facebook user correctly in the backend. Would love to see this solved by Parse itself.

Comment: I also added `[[PFUser currentUser] delete]` to delete to anonymous user from the database, as this user will not be needed anymore and would be a dead reference.

Comment: Unfortunately this look like the best answer. You will loose all data of the current user but the Facebook link will be done properly. Another problem is that the user gets 2 prompts to authorise Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore it as it's a warning to notify you that the Facebook account was already linked(In your case it's to the anonymous user), not an error.

The last assigned user will be linked to the Facebook account. So your original intention - " To link the currently active user to his to facebook account" works even though a warning will be raised to notify you that the anonymous user was linked to the same facebook account.

To avoid this warning, always logout the anonymous user before linking Facebook user with the currently active user.

Comment: actually if you always logout anonymous user before logging in to FB you will lose that connection, if you store userdata/preferences/activity which user did before FB connection, because that would create second user entry for the same person, so I think it is than better to ignore it or as in Jeremy's answer

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and solution was even better, just ignore this error. It is kind of warning. It is thrown but user gets linked to another account.

Comment: This is not true...just tested it and this was not the case

Answer (score -1):

Check if you are asking for permissions when you try to link like this:

```
[PFFacebookUtils linkUser:[PFUser currentUser] permissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"publish_actions", @"user_about_me", @"user_photos", @"read_stream",@"friends_photos",@"email",@"user_birthday",@"user_location", nil] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded) {
                [self login:nil];
                NSLog(@"Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
            }else{
                 NSLog(@"%@", [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"]);

                    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);

            }
        }];
```

In my case i was passing nil param for permissions. May be it will be helpfull for someone else